# Clifford operators acting on the exterior algebra bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras

I am reading Weiping Zhang's [lecture](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4756) and I encounter the following:

Suppose $M$ is a $n$-dimensional compact manifold. For any $e\in TM$, let $e^*\in T^*M$ corresponds to $e$ via $g^{TM}$. Let $c(e)$, $\hat{c}(e)$ be the Clifford operators acting on the exterior algebra bundle $\Lambda^*(T^*M)$ defined by 
$$ c(e)=e^*\wedge{}-i_e,\quad \hat{c}(e)=e^*\wedge{}+i_e  $$
where $e^*\wedge$ and $i_e$ are the standard notation for exterior and interior multiplications.

**My Question**: why we can derive the following identity can be seen in the context of Clifford algebra:
$$c(e)c(e')+c(e')c(e)=-2\langle e,e'\rangle$$
can we prove it by direct computation?

Comment: Are you missing some hats in the final equation?

Comment: Yes direct computation works.

Comment: @ziggurism Well, I just copied the formula from Zhang's book and it just looks like that. But I to do that? I mean I'm not quite familiar with the notations he used to defined $c$ and $\hat{c}$.

Comment: It should be $c(e)\hat{c}(e')+\hat{c}(e')c(e)=-2\langle e,e'\rangle$. With that correction, a direct computation can do it. Comment again if you still have trouble with that formula.

Comment: $$c(e)\hat{c}(e')+\hat{c}(e')c(e)=(e^*\wedge{}-i_e)(e'^*\wedge{}+i_{e'})+(e'^* \wedge +i_{e'})(e^* \wedge -i_e)$$ Then I don't how to continue. I should do some kind of cancellation but how? @ziggurism

Comment: Well for starters you can expand that expression (aka FOIL). But more importantly to decide that operators are equal you need to check that they take the same value on all arguments in the domain. In other words, you need to let these operators act on an element of the exterior bundle like $v\wedge v'\wedge\dotsb\wedge v'''$ (or use basis elements). Then remember that interior product with a vector is a degree-1 derivation on the graded exterior algebra.

Comment: @ziggurism Thanks a lot for your comments. I had calculate the desire answer. Just one word, It seems that the formula you suggest will yields 0, and Zhang's formula is correct. Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Oh really? I will check my sources and my calculation to see if I can confirm.

Comment: Hi fuxuan. Not sure what happened yesterday (calculation is erased), but today I confirm it is as you say. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: The notation $\Lambda^*(T^* M)$ is the same what you called $\bigwedge^{\bullet}(T^* M)$ in your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though @ziggurism had answered my question, I typed down the details in consideration of future audience.

Let $\omega \in \bigwedge^{\bullet} (T^{\ast} M)$. Apply it to the operator $c
(e) c (e') + c (e') c (e)$. Using the antisymmetric properties of wedge
product and interior product, we have
$$ \begin{array}{lll}
     {}[c (e) c (e') + c (e') c (e)] \omega & = & - i_e (e^{\prime \ast}
     \wedge \omega) - e^{\ast} \wedge (i_{e'} \omega)\\
     &  & - i_{e'} (e^{\ast} \wedge \omega) - e^{\prime \ast} \wedge (i_e
     \omega)
   \end{array} $$
By the product rule of interior product, we have
$$ i_e (e^{\prime \ast} \wedge \omega) = i_e^{} (e^{\prime \ast}) \wedge
   \omega + (- 1) e^{\prime \ast} \wedge i_e \omega $$
and
$$ i_{e'} (e^{\ast} \wedge \omega) = i_{e'}^{} (e^{\ast}) \wedge \omega + (-
   1) e^{\ast} \wedge i_{e'} \omega . $$
We know that
$$ i_e (e^{\prime \ast}) = (e^{\prime \ast}, e) = \langle e', e \rangle $$
where $(e^{\prime \ast}, e)$ is the duality pairing.

Similary, $$i_{e'} (e^{\ast}) = \langle e, e'
\rangle.$$ Put in all these results to the first formula, we get
$$ [c (e) c (e') + c (e') c (e)] \omega = - 2 \langle e, e' \rangle \omega .
$$